# Retrieve approximate Hessian inverse from L-BFGS-B

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization, hessian-matrix

With the L-BFGS-B minimizer in scipy, is it possible to retrieve the approximate inverse Hessian that's calculated internally?

Having it in the implicit factored form, so that it's possible to compute arbitrary inverse Hessian matrix - vector products, would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's now a way to do this in SciPy.

Example:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen
result = minimize(rosen, x0=[0] * 10, method='L-BFGS-B')
print(result.hess_inv.todense())
```

Seems to have been added in SciPy 0.16.0. See the [PR](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4572) for this feature.

Comment: Yeah. I asked this question and subsequently submitted that code to scipy.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear so.  I'm not an expert on these algorithms but it seems that with L-BFGS specifically it is not possible.  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS):

> Instead of the inverse Hessian H_k, L-BFGS maintains a history of the past m updates of the position x and gradient ∇f(x), where generally the history size m can be small (often m<10). These updates are used to implicitly do operations requiring the H_k-vector product.

However, if you use [`scipy.fmin_bfgs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs) it *does* return the approximate (inverse of the) Hessian matrix, at the cost of the greater memory needed to maintain it.

Comment: After the optimization is finished, *I* would like to do some other calculations that only required inverse-Hessian matrix products, so the implicit representation is fine.

Comment: It looks like all of what you would need for that can be found in the original implementation's [working array](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb/lbfgsb.f#L363).  Unfortunately it looks like SciPy's high-level wrapper for it does not return that.  However, if you use the low-level interface directly to the FORTRAN function you should be able to get at it, as demonstrated here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py#L199  Bit of a pain, but you could modify that to return the working array `wa` as well.